# How to make existing maven parent project, child of newly created maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, parent-child, parent-pom

I have existing maven Project(named as **projectB**) that is **parent** of other Projects(projectC and projectD), and I want to make **projectB** as child of newly created maven Project(named as projectA). This is Directory structure:

```
projectA
  -> pom.xml
projectB
  -> pom.xml
projectC
  -> pom.xml
projectD
  -> pom.xml
```

This is how my `pom.xml` of **projectA** looks:

```
<modules>
    <module>projectB</module>
</modules>
```

And this is my `pom.xml` of **projectB** Looks:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>(groupId of projectA)</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modules>
        <module>../projectC</module>
        <module>../projectD</module>
    </modules>
```

But when I perform `make clean` on **projectA** it gives me error:

> Child module C:\Users\projectB of C:\Users\projectA\pom.xml does not exist

I have searched existing solutions, but none has helped me in solving the problem.

Comment: Could you also add the `parent` section of project C's POM? Does it contain the `relativePath` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your all projects are all in the same level, you should have:

In Project A:

```
<modules>
    <module>../projectB</module>
</modules>
```

And in Project B:

```
<parent>
    ...
    <relativePath>../projectA/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: i changed that: it gives error which Shows that modules try to find ProjectB inside projectA. ``Child module C:\Users\projectB\..\projectA of C:\Users\projectA\pom.xml does not exist``

Comment: @RajjatDadwal Are you sure, that this error message is correct? No typo? It makes no sense, that your project A is a child module of itself. Maybe it is better, to show the real error message.

Answer (score -1):

Below Configuration in pom.xml of Project B is incorrect

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>(groupId of projectB)</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

In parent section, you have to specify Project A not B. Something like below should help

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>(groupId of projectA)</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>(Project A version)</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: @sumit please read the question again. How can parent pom file have the ```parent``` tag?

Comment: @RajjatDadwal you are saying that B is also a child of A (though it is parent as well for C and D)? In that case you have to specfy both its childs (or Modules) and parent in pom.xml of B. Please let me know if I am missing somethinhg here.

Comment: @RameshKumar: Project B is parent POM of project C, but also child POM of project A, so sumit singh is right, project B's POM needs a `parent` section refering project A's POM.

Comment: @sumitsingh sorry I have edited that. actually in my real code it is correct. I just did mistake in the post. Still it gives same error.

Comment: @RajjatDadwal so could you atleast remove the downvote for my answer